# Cast Protocol to Class in Swift

Tags: swift

When we do optional chaining like

```
var myVar: Int?

if let unwrapped = myVar {

}
```

Compiler treat `unwrapped` as `Int`

I have array of classes that conform to specific protocol. Consider example:

```
import Foundation

protocol SomeProtocol: class {}

class A {}
extension A: SomeProtocol {}
class B {}
extension B: SomeProtocol {}
class C {}
extension C: SomeProtocol {}

let arr: [SomeProtocol] = [A(), B(), C()]

arr.forEach{ object in
  if object is A {
    // object is treated like SomeProtocol, not like A class
  }
}
```

I can do `(object as! A)` but this is look ugly. How can i find a way to smart cast protocol item to variable of my class?

Comment: I guess this is the only valid way so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path with optional binding.

`as?` is a variation of `as!` that evaluates to an optional of the type to which you are casting. You can use this in conjunction with optional binding:

```
arr.forEach{ object in
  if let a = object as? A { // (object as? A) is of type "A?", but we are unwrapping it
    // a is of type A now
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I thought as? is only used when you deal with optionals.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban It also can be used when you want to cast. It evaluates to nil if the cast fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case let` to clean it up a bit. Taking your example above, it can be changed to

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {}

class A {}
extension A: SomeProtocol {}
class B {}
extension B: SomeProtocol {}
class C {}
extension C: SomeProtocol {}

let arr: [SomeProtocol] = [A(), B(), C()]

for case let object as A in arr {
    print("item is A")
}
```

This will loop through the array and if the item can be cast to the specified type, the body of the for loop will execute. It just removes a line of nesting and looks a bit cleaner, although it is ultimately the same as Sweeper's answer above

Answer (score 2):

**Use *Pattern Matching* in a `switch` Statement**

If you are going to be processing multiple types in the same loop, using a `switch` with *pattern matching* to establish the type is handy:

**Example:**

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {}

class A {
    let foo = 17
}
extension A: SomeProtocol {}
class B {
    let bar = "hello"
}
extension B: SomeProtocol {}
class C {
    let baz = true
}
extension C: SomeProtocol {}
class D: SomeProtocol {}

let arr: [SomeProtocol] = [D(), A(), C(), B()]

for object in arr {
    switch object {
    case let a as A:
        print("object is A")
        print(a.foo)
    case let b as B:
        print("object is B")
        print(b.bar)
    case let c as C:
        print("object is C")
        print(c.baz)
    default:
        print("object is some other type")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> object is some other type
> object is A
> 17
> object is C
> true
> object is B
> hello
> ```